# Determine if the elements in arrays are arranged accordingly

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have arrays `basket = ["O", "P", "W", "G"]` and  `sack = ["G", "P", "O", "W"]`. How can I compare these arrays to determine if the elements are arranged in the same order on not?

Comment: Will the two arrays have same number of elements and same elements ?

Comment: They will have the same number of elements, but the elements may and may not be the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect you to supply the minimal code you used to try to solve the problem. As is it doesn't look like you tried anything and want us to solve it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I was able to come up with.

```
ordered = 0
disordered = 0
index = 0
while index < basket.length

  if basket[index] == sack[index] 
       ordered+= 1     
  elsif basket.include?(sack[index]) && (basket[index] != sack[index])
        disordered+= 1
  end
  index += 1
end

puts" there are #{ordered} ordered common items and #{disordered} disordered common items"
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
basket == sack #=> false, for given values
```

If you compare them, having the same order:

```
basket.sort == sack.sort #=> true
```

Also, please check "[Comparing two arrays in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9095017/1426097)" for a discussion on comparing arrays.

Comment: How does basket.sort == sack.sort prove that two arrays were in same order? it just proves that two array have same elements

Comment: @WandMaker It was just to illustrate the first statement.

Comment: Yeah @WandMaker calling `Array#sort` will mutate the order of the elements in the array. So that's not going to help you determine if the two arrays are in the same order, but will only help you find out if they both have exactly the same terms.

Answer (score 0):

If both arrays can contain different number of elements and possibly some extra elements, and you want to find out whether those elements that are common to both arrays appear in exact same order, then, you could do something like below:

```
basket = ["D", "O", "P", "W", "G", "C"] 
sack = ["Z", "O", "W", "P", "G", "X"]

p (basket - (basket - sack)) == (sack - (sack - basket))
```