# Ruby : How to compare 2 arrays of string

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, compare

I have 2 arrays of strings as under. I want to compare them and execute some code if these arrays are not equal-

```
current_instances  = ["170601_7711", "170601_8811"]
app_instances      = ["170602_7711", "170602_8811"]
```

How can I compare them in ruby?

Comment: You should give some efforts before asking question in SO and then provide the solution what you've tried.

Comment: Is it possible that there a duplicates in (in one or both of) the arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two arrays in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095017/comparing-two-arrays-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

```
x = ["alpha1", "beta1"]
y = ["alpha2", "beta2"]
```

#### Check if all elements are the same

```
x == y #=> false
```

#### Compare each element

Compare each string at some index i, assuming both arrays are the same size. Then apply some code to the matches.

```
x.zip(y) #=> [["alpha1", "alpha2"], ["beta1", "beta2"]]
x.zip(y).map {|a,b| a == b ? 'do this' : 'else do this' }
#=> ["else do this", "else do this"]
```

Comment: Nice solution to check by each element, if order matters. Thanks :]

Comment: @Nils_e Thanks for the kind feedback, Ruby is a very elegant language:)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do an array difference with the `-` operator and execute your code if the difference is zero

```
arr_diff = current_instances - app_instances
```

This is the simplest solution I could think of :)

Check my [solution](https://eval.in/823351) and let me know how it goes